# How should I version my data in an MS SQL shared server environment?

Tags: php, database, sql-server-2008, versioning

The server is a shared Windows hosting server with Hostgator. We are allowed "unlimited" MS SQL databases and each is allowed "unlimited" space. I'm writing the website in PHP. The data (not the DB schema, but the data) needs to be versioned such that (ideally) my client can select the DB version he wants from a select box when he logs in to the website, and then (roughly once a month) tag the current data, also through a simple form on the website. I've thought of several theoretical ways to do this and I'm not excited about any of them.

1) Put a VersionNumber column on every table; have a master Version table that lists all versions for the select box at login. When tagged, every row without a version number in every table in the db would be duplicated, and the original would be given a version number.

This seems like the easiest idea for both me and my client, but I'm concerned the db would be awfully slow in just a few months, since every table will grow by (at least) its original size every month. There's not a whole lot of data, and there probably never will be, in any one version. But multiplying versions in the same table just scares me.

2) Duplicate the DB every time we tag.

It looks like this would have to be done manually by my client since the server is shared, so I already dislike the idea. But in addition, the old DBs would have to be able to work with the current website code, and as changes are made to the DB structure over time (which is inevitable) the old DBs will no longer work with the new website code.

3) Create duplicate tables (with the version in their name) inside the same database every time we tag. Like [v27_Employee].

The benefit here over idea (1) would be that no table would get humongous in size, allowing the queries to keep up their speed, and over idea (2) it could theoretically be done easily through the simple website tag form rather than manually by my client. The problems are that the queries in my PHP code are going to get all discombobulated as I try to explain which Employee table is joining with which Address table depending upon which version is selected, since they all have the same name, but different; and also that as the code changes, the old DB tables no longer match, same problem as (2).

So, finally, does anyone have any good recommendations? Best practices? Things they did that worked in the past?

Thanks guys.

Comment: You might get better answers if you explain more about WHY you need this versioning. Versioning data is a common requirement (look at WordPress posts for a great example), but the way you're versioning (by "tagging" data and essentially asking for a snapshot in time) is pretty unusual. What's the use-case?

Comment: Additionally- how often does data change? Does ALL of the data change for each version, or will only a few parts of the data change per version tag?

Comment: The whole DB is approximately 15 megs. I expect the "current" data will not ever grow terribly much beyond that. Maybe 30 Megs tops. They'll probably do roughly one data release a month. The data is the product my client sells... if a piece of it changes, other pieces have to change to maintain the product's integrity, and changing all the pieces correctly takes a team of people around the world about a month. How would you recommend versioning the data other than tagging it? FYI, the DB is MS SQL 2008. I'm using SQL 2008 Express for Admin purposes.

Comment: I've been thinking I might go with a previous versions table, so each model will have two tables. The previous versions table will have multiple previous versions in it, so it will grow and grow while the current data table (the one they will almost always use) will always be fast and efficient. The previous versions can eventually be manually exported and archived if they become unwieldy. Pros? Cons? Thanks again.

Comment: I think this is a case of not doing a good requirement analysis beforehand. This versioning feature should be designed early. What data need multiple versions? When do they expire? @gcdev your last comment is recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally wound up doing was creating a new schema for each version and duplicating the tables and triggers and keys each time the DB is versioned. So, for example, I had this table:

```
[dbo].[TableWithData]
```

And I duplicated it into this table in the same DB:

```
[v1].[TableWithData]
```

Then, when the user wants to view old tables, they select which version and my code automatically changes every instance of `[dbo]` in every query to `[v1]`. It's conceptually fairly simple and the user doesn't have to do anything complicated to version -- just type in "v1" to a form and hit a submit button. My PHP and SQL does the rest.

I did find that some tables had to remain separate -- I made a different schema called `[ctrl]` into which I put tables that will not be versioned, like the username / password table for example. That way I just duplicate the `[dbo]` tables.

Its been operational for a year or so and seems to work well at the moment. They've only versioned maybe 4 times so far. The only problem I seem to have consistently that I can't figure out is that triggers seem to get lost somehow. That's probably a problem with my very complex PHP rather than the DB versioning concept itself though.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the most obvious solution because it has the lowest maintenance overhead and it's the easiest to work with: you can view any version at any time simply by adding @VersionNumber to your queries. If you want or need to, this means you could also implement option 3 at the same time by creating views for each version number instead of real tables. If your application only queries one version at a time, consider making the VersionNumber the first column of a clustered primary key, so that all the data for one version is physically stored together.

And it isn't clear how much data you have anyway. You say it's "not a whole lot", but that means nothing. If you really have a lot of data (say, into hundreds of millions of rows) and if you have Enterprise Edition (you didn't say what edition you're using), you can use table partitioning to 'split' very large tables for better performance.

My conclusion would be to do the simplest, easiest thing to maintain right now. If it works fine then you're done. If it doesn't, you will at least be able to rework your design from a simple, stable starting point. If you do something more complicated now, you will have much more work to do if you ever need to redesign it.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your versionable tables into a new database every month. If you need to do a join between a versionable table and a non-versionable table, you'd need to do a cross-schema join - which is supported in SQL Server. This approach is a bit cleaner than duplicating tables in a single schema, since your database explorer will start getting unwieldy with all the old tables.